# Controlling Windows 10 update time

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-task-scheduler

I am connected to an Internet connection that is free of charge from 1 o'clock to 7 in the morning and want to schedule this in windows 10. it means I want to set task scheduler to set my WiFi metered status as off at 1 o'clock  and set it as on at 7 o'clock every day in the morning.I want just put metered status of my WiFi at for example 1 o'clock everyday off and at 7 o'clock on when my Windows 10 is running and I am logged on to only control windows 10 auto updating and yet having access to any online Internet information.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read ***[ask]***, then [edit] your question to include a specific question and details of what you have already attempted in order to resolve this on your own.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "metered status" (that sounds like it relates to your ISP and how they charge, in which case circumventing it would be off-topic).  Windows 10 is going to update some time.  Are you saying you just want to schedule that so it isn't during the free period?  If so, why would you want to pay to download updates when you can do it for free?  Are you using 100% of your bandwidth from 1 to 7 and downloads would degrade that usage?

Answer (score 1):

it only took about 9 months for you to get a proper answer, but here goes :)

This was a valid question despite the comments you got. I'm in a similar situation where my ISP allows 150GB of downloads per month, apart from midnight to 8am where downloads do not count towards our monthly limit. We need to stop Windows 10 being so greedy with our data during monitored hours and the way to do that is to set the wireless connections as 'metered' during these hours.

You will need to use NETSH to do the work - I wasted a few hours trying to do this via WMI but failed. To list all wifi profiles that your PC knows about run this in PowerShell (or command prompt):

```
netsh.exe WLAN show profiles
```

You will get a result something like this:

> Profiles on interface WiFi:
>
> Group policy profiles (read only)
>
> User profiles
>
> All User Profile     : upstairs
>
> All User Profile     : _stanstedairport WiFi
>
> All User Profile     : downstairs
>
> All User Profile     : Starbucks

Copy the names after the colon so that you get the case right as that is important and enter the ones that you want into this powershell script:

```
# Sets the following wireless profiles as metered
$WifiProfiles = @('upstairs','downstairs')
foreach($WifiProfile in $WifiProfiles){
    netsh.exe WLAN set profileparameter name=$WifiProfile cost="fixed"
}
```

Save that as a *.PS1 file and use the task scheduler to launch it at the time you want. If you've not used the task scheduler with PowerShell before, in the "Actions" tab enter:

> PowerShell.exe

in the "Program/script:" box, and in the "Add Arguments" box enter:

> -file "C:\path to your file\your file.PS1"

You'll then need a new script for to set the wireless profiles back to unmetered - use this:

```
# Sets the following wireless profiles as unmetered
$WifiProfiles = @('upstairs', 'downstairs')
foreach($WifiProfile in $WifiProfiles)
{
    netsh.exe WLAN set profileparameter name=$WifiProfile cost="unrestricted"
}
```

Hope that is useful to you.